# how to reprecent catched imge in offline mod

Tags: android

hello my app works in two modes i.e offline and online.When selected as offline my app prepare for offline mode catches the json and saves it in database.In online mode it represents image and text but in offline mod just it's supposed to represent cached text and images,but it doesn't. why ? (i think it receives image but doesn't represent it).what should i do

```
  protected  Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        jsonarray = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(mUrl2);


                if ( internetpresent )
                {
                    db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        map.put("id", jsonobject.getString("id"));
                        map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
                        map.put("type1", jsonobject.getString("type1"));
                        map.put("type", jsonobject.getString("type"));
                        map.put("matn", jsonobject.getString("matn"));
                        map.put("date", jsonobject.getString("date"));
                        map.put("address", jsonobject.getString("address"));

                        arraylist.add(map);
                        long id = db.InsertNewEntity(jsonobject.getInt("id"),jsonobject.getString("title"),
                                jsonobject.getString("type"),jsonobject.getString("matn"),jsonobject.getString("date"),hid
                                ,jsonobject.getString("type1"),jsonobject.getString("_new"),jsonobject.getString("address"));

                    }
```

Comment: which lib are you using for image loading ?

Comment: من از لایبرری در این پروژه استفاده نکردم

Comment: nothing use lib in this project

Comment: please post your image loading code

Comment: i dont have code for load image all code for get json and save in database above

Comment: In online mode your App shows Images ?

Comment: yes but in offlne dont show

Comment: so give that code of image loading ?

Comment: if ( p.getTypeField().equals("img") )
                {
                    matn = p.getImgSrc();
                    map.put("type", p.getTypeField());
                }

Comment: in offline mod get img but dont show

Comment: means u r getting path of images over http in offline mode , correct ?

Comment: feel free to up vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of the libs below.

Nostra’s Universal Image loader – https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Picasso – http://square.github.io/picasso/

Both are very great for caching images offline.

Comment: thanks but can you help me what change s in above code